# npm install expo-cli error after installing Node12LTS and afterset configuration

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Error while installing `npm install expo-cli`

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.15.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.15.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."^1.1.1","standard":"'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

config like this using https://medium.com/@nbanzyme/easy-way-to-install-nvm-on-ubuntu-18-04-2cfb19ee5391:

```
$ export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"    
$ [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
$ [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```